# Caml Query returns all the values from sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query

i am using a caml query to check if a specific value exist in a sharepoint list. but it ends up returnning all the values instead of one.

```
          while (reader.Read())
                {
                 //   MessageBox.Show(reader[5].ToString());
                    CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                    camlQuery.ViewXml =
                        @"<Query>
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name='Email_x0020_Address' />
    <Value Type='Text'>myname@domain.com</Value> </Eq></Where></Query>";
                    ListItemCollection listItems = myList.GetItems(camlQuery);
                    ctx.Load(
                         listItems
                         );
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                    if (listItems.Count != 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Item Exists");
                        foreach (ListItem listItem in listItems.ToList())
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(listItem["Email_x0020_Address"].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Item Does not exists");
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing **View** tag.

Please try to put your query inside **View** tag. It will retrieve filtered data only.

```
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            ...
            ...
            ...
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
```

Comment: even with adding view tag its the same

Answer (score -1):

Removing the Query keyword could work.

```
camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Email_x0020_Address' /<Value Type='Text'>myname@domain.com</Value></Eq></Where>";
```

Alternatively, you can try to first append all the items in the list to a List of ListItem and then do your query by using LINQ. It was suggested to me by someone in here and I find it easier, more structured and never fails in large data sets (unlike CAML Query which does not work with over 5000 items).

Comment: not working with this <Where> <Eq> <FieldRef Name='Email_x0020_Address' /> <Value Type='Text'>myemail@mydomain.com</Value> </Eq></Where>. but when i ran it directly in caml query builder it returns only one record. from visual studio its 1017 the total number of records